# How to use grep command in linux with []

Tags: bash, grep

I want to use grep command to check if [200] after the space exist in this string

```
https://wwww.example.com/2000/file200.js [200]
https://wwww.example.com/2020/file201.js [404]
```

I tried to grep "[200]" and grep "\[200\]"
but none of them worked.

I need to save the link too after checking with grep so for example it will be something like this

`cat links.txt | grep "[200]" > output.txt`

the `output.txt` should contain the links, not the status codes.

Edit: It works with `echo` but it doesn't work with `cat` or when I try to give the input from another command.
The command should be like `Command | grep "[200]" | cut -d' ' -f1 > New links`

Comment: What does `none of them worked` mean? Was there an error message or incorrect output? `grep "\[200\]"` does match on GNU grep. Is the problem that you want to remove the status code after matching?

Comment: It doesn't match with `SomeCommand | grep "\[200\]" | cut -d' ' -f1 > New links`

Comment: Can you show output of `some_command | cat -vte`

Comment: Here is the output of  `some_command | cat-vte` ==> `https://www.google.com/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/alpha/invisible.js [^[[32m200^[[0m]$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're getting colored output using your command. You may use this `grep`:

```bash
some_command | grep '\[[^]]*200[^]]*]'

https://wwww.example.com/2000/file200.js [200]
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\[`: Match a `[`
- `[^]]*`: Match 0 or of any characters that are not `]`
- `200`: Match text `200`
- `[^]]*`: Match 0 or of any characters that are not `]`
- `]`: Match a `]`

Comment: Aw, Thank you so much. I just noticed that so I removed the color option now `grep "\[200\]"` works fine for me as well as the command you provided. Thanks again

Comment: Indeed, your output of `cat-vte` helped trace the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

> -F, --fixed-strings       PATTERNS are strings

```bash
grep -F '[^[[32m200^[[0m]' file | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Comment: Pipe it to `cut -d' ' -f1` should get only the links/url.

Comment: @Jetchisel Yes, I missed that part too. It is mentioned in the question at the very bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Your example works perfectly for me with the escapes in

```
 echo "https://wwww.example.com/99/file99.js [200]" | grep "\[200\]"
```

Then if you just want the first part you can use `awk` which is like a mini programming language you can use in the terminal. Where `print $1` just prints the characters before the first space

```
echo "https://wwww.example.com/99/file99.js [200]" | grep "\[200\]" | awk '{print $1}'
```

OUTPUT:

```
https://wwww.example.com/99/file99.js
```

Comment: `grep ... | awk ...` is an anti-pattern. You don't need `grep` when you use `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/ \[200]$//p' links.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

- the whole line

> ```
> nawk 'NF *= ($-_)~__' __=' [[]200[]]$' 
> gawk 'NF *= ($NF)~__' __='[[]200[]]'
> mawk 'NF*=/ [[]200[]]$/'
> ```

```
https://wwww.example.com/2000/file200.js [200]
```

- just the `URL`

> ```
> gawk 'NF = !_<NF' OFS= FS=' [[]200[]]$'
>                             # personally I prefer consistent approach
> nawk 'NF = / [[]200[]]$/'   # when escaping "[" and "]" instead of
> mawk 'NF = / \[200]$/'      # <—- this asymmetric but still POSIX-compliant one
> ```

```
https://wwww.example.com/2000/file200.js
```